# Return instance of class that is in another solution

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I'm remodeling one project from my company which is in bad conditions, the thing is that I divided the project in 3 layers (3 Solutions):

- (SOLUTION 1) One solution is the client side (Which contain all the forms)
- (SOLUTION 2) Another one to call stored procedures and return the value from database.
- (SOLUTION 3) And finally another one which is in the middle of previounes one, that contains all the bussiness logic.

SOLUTION 1 -(CALLS)-> SOLUTION 3 -(CALLS)-> SOLUTION 2

So the thing is in SOLUTION 2 I create classes that are models (which I use for calling methods), and I want to use this models in my other two classes, but I'm trying to avoid create the same class and mapping every propertie from one solution to another solution.

Is there any way to return an instance like this?

**SOLUTION 2:**

> ```
> Public Class Example
>  private int _number;
>
>  public int Number
>  {
>    get  {
>     return _number; 
>   }
>
>    set {
>     _number = value;
>    }
>  }
> End Class
> ```

**SOLUTION 3:**

> ```
> Public Class Example
>
>   Public Example(){
>    return SOLUTION2.Example;
> }
> ```

**SOLUTION 1:**

> ```
> Public Class Example
>
>   Public Example(){
>    return SOLUTION3.Example;
> }
> End Class;
> ```

Comment: The question title talks about different projects but the question talks about different solutions.So: are we talking projects or solutions?

Comment: Sorry I edit the title, we are talking about solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add all three projects to a new solution (solution 4) and then add references between the projects.

To add a reference; right click on the project and select Add, then Reference.  Then select the appropriate project.  For example, select Project 3 (currently part of Solution 3) for Project 1 (currently part of Solution 1) and Project 2 (currently part of Solution 2) for Project 3.

After adding the reference you will have to import (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using) the class e.g.

```
using Project1.Example
```

Comment: Yeah, but i'm trying to avoid circular references, i want that the aplicattion (3 solutions) work in one direction (SOLUTION 2 => SOLUTION 3 => SOLUTION 1)